# Extraxt URL from response.text()

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, libcurl

I want to extract id of result not target(79 and 12) and it's url(of target) from the following response (finding).

finding:

```
{"count":87,
   
   "results":[
      {
         "id":79,
         "target":
             {
                 {"id":567,"url":"https://demo.com
",.....},
          "(...)"
         ,
         "id":12,
         "target":
         
          "(...)"
         ,
         "id":32,
         "target":
          "(...)"
         ,"(....)"
}
]
}
```

How can I extract these id's and URL's and store in form of a dist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your sample code is incorrect. Assuming the data under `results` is a list of dictionaries, you can use dict comprehension:

```
urls = {i["id"]: i["target"]["site"]["url"] for i in findings["results"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `python dictionary comprehension`

```
new_dict = {i["id"]: i['target']["site"]["url"] for i in finding["results"]}
```